# How to remove a CNAME from EC2 Amazon Linux Server?

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2, cname

if I got to my server via ssh and execute

dig sub.domain.com I get:

> sub.domain.com.        1800    IN      CNAME   domain.com.

I want to remove that. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the record is served from the DNS server. You will need to remove it from there. Once removed, the dns lookup may be cached as long (in some cases longer) than the ttl assigned to the record.

Comment: Do you know how to access the DNS settings of an EC2 server?

Comment: You need to access the dns settings for your domain, not the server. Assuming you have access to that.